# katalon recorder can't read date picker upon running

Tags: datepicker, katalon-recorder, katalon

After recording the module,Katalon recorder can't read the date picker upon playback.

check the screenshot: [datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3B1C.jpg)

how can i handle this stuff?

Comment: need detalization: some code and (for example) the error log are you getting.

Comment: 'element can't be found' even if it is recorded. i use set text command as remedy to that issue